# How to update a column with different values in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with name "User_Report" with these columns.

```
ID       Name    City    zip    Report_File
101      AAA     PPP     123     -----
102      BBB     QQQ     345     -----
103      CCC     RRR     567     -----
104      FFF     SSS     789     -----
```

I added Report_File new column and i need to update this column with Name+".rpt".
How i can update Report_File column with corressponding Name column data in a single update statement?

Please send me one example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query. In oracle double pipes (`||`) are used for concatenation of strings:

```
Update User_Report
SET Report_File=Name||'.rpt';
```

OR keyword `CONCAT` can be used. Refer [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)

```
Update User_Report
SET Report_File=CONCACT(Name, '.rpt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your report_file column appears to be a calculated value, if it will never deviate, then you might consider a virtual column.

```
alter table user_report add (report_file varchar(40) as (name||'.rpt'));
```

This way you never have to worry about keeping it in synch, it will always be in synch if name changes or new values are inserted.